# Is firewire still supported by Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10, firewire

If it's not, then should I download a third party program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireWire devices work plug and play on all currently available versions of Ubuntu. To list the available FireWire packages run `apt search firewire` and filter the search results by *IEEE 1394* and *IEEE1394*.

Here is a list of a few FireWire packages that are in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu and also Ubuntu 20.04.

- libavc1394-0
- libavc1394-dev
- libavc1394-tools
- libdc1394-22
- libdc1394-22-dbg
- libdc1394-22-dev
- libdc1394-utils
- libraw1394-11
- libraw1394-tools

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this answer, four years on, support for firewire on Ubuntu is pledged until at least 2029. See here: [www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Firewire-New-Maintainer](http://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Firewire-New-Maintainer)

But as of Ubuntu 20.04 (or thereabouts), permissions were changed so you have to do a bit of tweaking to get dvgrab to work. You have to add a rule for firewire in /etc/udev/rules.d

```
sudo nano /etc/rules.d/80-firewire.rules
```

This will open a new file in rules.d in which a single line is needed:

```
KERNEL=="fw*", GROUP="video", MODE="0664"
```

Then you have to add yourself to the video group:

```
sudo adduser <yourname> video
```

Explanation for this was found here: https://superuser.com/questions/236562/permanently-changing-permission-of-firewire-device